# jquery checkbox and textbox validation

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textbox

I have this submit button which will only enable if user entered a word on all textfields as well as  chose at least one from my checkboxes. So here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAddUser').attr('disabled', true);

    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
    $('#txtName' && '#txtLastname').on("keyup", action);

    function action() {
        if ($('#txtName' && '#txtLastname').val().length > 0) {
            $('#btnAddUser').attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('#btnAddUser').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    }

    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
        submitButt = $("#btnAddUser");

    checkboxes.click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#btnAddUser').prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('#btnAddUser').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

my function for textboxes and checkboxes were currently separated, how am I going to join it together in one function so that It won't enable submit button if the user did not entered a word in the textboxes and chose any of the checkboxes available. Thanks! I just really need to get this done as soon as possible.

Comment: No need  of `action` inside `ready`

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created 2 propertes, `disabled1` and `disabled2`.
The first one holds the validation of the textfields the second one holds it for the checkboxes.

If both validations succeeds then the button gets enabled else disabled.

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var disabled1 = true;
    var disabled2 = true;

    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
    $('#txtName' && '#txtLastname').on("keyup", function() {
        if ($('#txtName' && '#txtLastname').val().length > 0) {
            disabled1 = false;
        } else {
            disabled1 = true;
        }
        loadButton();
    });

    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
        // Check if at least one checkbox is selected or more
        if ($(':checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
            disabled2 = false;
        } else {
            disabled2 = true;
        }
        loadButton();
    });

    function loadButton() {
        if(!disabled1 && !disabled2) {
            $('#btnAddUser').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else{
            $('#btnAddUser').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }

    loadButton();
});
```

See jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/xdvh05yy/1/

Comment: this one worked! thanks. but I have two categories on using checkbox. They should pick at least one on each category. here's the jsfiddle of my work https://jsfiddle.net/a1qrtfva/

Comment: No problem please mark the answer so that others can view the solution.

Comment: I just have this one last question how am I going to code the submit button to disable when the first textbox has no input because currently, all fields can be validated except from my first textbox. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $btn = $('#btnAddUser').prop('disabled', true);

  var $checks = $("input[type='checkbox']").click(action);

  //use multiple selectors
  var $texts = $('#txtName, #txtLastname').on("keyup", action);

  function action() {
    $btn.prop('disabled', !$checks.is(':checked') || $texts.filter(function() {
      return !this.value.trim().length
    }).length > 0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<br />
<input id="txtName" />
<input id="txtLastname" />
<br />
<input id="btnAddUser" type="button" value="Save" />
```